# How to submit form on success when function return false?

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I have a form which has a click event. When the create button is clicked, this event occurs:

(Note: I'm using Wordpress so the 'jQuery' equals '$')

```
jQuery('.btn-create').click(function(e){

    var charname = jQuery('.charname').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://bemlocal.vn/validate.php',
        data: 'charname='  + charname,
        success: function(message) {
            if(message == 'ok') {
                jQuery('#charnameForm').submit();
            }
            else {
                jQuery('.message').text(message);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

By default, this form can not be submitted because of return false at the end of the function. But I want to submit this form when the status of ajax call is success and the message is "ok". I try many ways but the form still can not be submitted.

How to solve this problem?

**Updated:** I have a mistake. Because I turned on the debug mode in Wordpress `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` so the message contains the notice of PHP, not only the message of ajax call. It leads to the condition of message check is not true, and the form could not be submitted.

I turned of the debug mode and it worked!

Comment: what is the purpose of using return false ?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the `message` variable is `ok`?

Comment: @Oliboy50: The purpose is to prevent submitting by default. I just want to submit the form when the status of ajax call is success and the message is "ok" only. In case of success and the message is not "ok", the form will not be submitted.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thank you. I have a mistake here. I checked, the `message` variable is not `ok`, it is `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\...</b> on line <b>97</b><br />
ok`. Because I turn on debug mode in wp-config.php file (`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`), so it will display the notice and message instead of the message only. It leads to the condition is not true, and the form not be submitted. I tried to turn of the dubug mode  and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

change code

**before**

```
jQuery('#charnameForm').submit();
```

**after**

```
jQuery('#charnameForm')[0].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have the explanation above. Or you can read the updated comment in the topic.

Comment: @Nguyễn Trọng Bằng - Oh, I see. Thank you for letting comment.